# Variavel via POST para sed

Tags: php, formulário, raspberry-pi, sed

Eu estou com um raspbian rodando num raspberry pi3, estou fazendo um sistema em cima dele que necessita que a pessoa escolha o *hostname* digitando ele num campo. E para trocar o *hostname* do rasp eu preciso alterar dois arquivos dentro da pasta etc. Já consegui fazer essas alteração pelo comando `sed`, porém como quero que a pessoa escolha o *hostname*, fiz um formulário por PHP e queria pegar via POST essa variável e repassar para o comando `sed`. Segue o códigos.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<form method="POST">

<input  type="text" name="hostname">
<input type="submit" name="Comentar" value=" Salvar">

</form>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['Comentar'])){   
        echo "botão foi clicado"."<br/>";
        $SEU_HOSTNAME = $_POST["hostname"];
        echo  "hostname digitado: ".$SEU_HOSTNAME; 


    shell_exec ('

        cd /etc/

        sudo sed -i "s/nome/${SEU_HOSTNAME}/" hosts
        sudo sed -i "s/nome/${SEU_HOSTNAME}/" hostname


    ');

    }

?>
```

Fazendo desta forma, aparece somente as { } no arquivo que modifico.
Alguém saberia o que pode ser isso?

Comment: Osmar, [não poste código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132), o site tem suporte para os códigos, basta utilizá-los. Você pode fazer o [tour] para aprender o básico do site, ler o guia de [ask] e acessas a [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Para que o arquivo PHP consiga alterar o arquivo, ele deve ser executado como sudo e tente mudar o código para o seguinte:

```
$command1 = 'sudo sed -i "s/nome/'.$SEU_HOSTNAME.'/" hosts';
$command2 = 'sudo sed -i "s/nome/'.$SEU_HOSTNAME.'/" hostname';

shell_exec("cd /etc/");
shell_exec($command1);
shell_exec($command2);
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Exatamente isso, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo desta maneira também consegui resultado. Depois de testar o código acima, pesquisei mais um pouco e achei esta solução.

```
$HOSTNAME=escapeshellarg("s/nome/$SEU_HOSTNAME/");
shell_exec ("
    cd /etc/
    sudo sed -i $HOSTNAME hosts
    sudo sed -i $HOSTNAME hostname
");
```